# SSRS 2008 rendering HTML in reports

Tags: html, reporting-services, rendering

I have an SSRS 2008 Reporting app.  Several of the fields in the database are stored in Escaped HTML.  Below is an example:

```
&lt;p&gt;   &amp;bull; ABC 123 leadership will be required from January 2013 through July 2015 based on proposal schedule included in the 123 proposal kick-off package&lt;br /&gt;   &lt;br /&gt;   &amp;bull; 65 deliverable ABCs (57 new ABCs required for DEF and 8 ABC kits carried over from F404 contract) will be build to print ABC-107s &amp;ndash; no effort is included in this bid to modify the design of these production units.&lt;br /&gt;   &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
```

**Clarifying why data is stored as HTML**.
We are using CkEditor RTF text areas in order to allow the user to enter formatted data into our web app which ther SSRS reports are launched from.

Is there a way to render this in an SSRS report formatted and looking like it would in an HTML Web Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Custom Report Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345231.aspx) with code that renders html or if you just need to reformat text then [Custom Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159238.aspx) will be enough

Comment: @Orsol....outstanding.  I added a reference to System.Web in the report properties.  Then added code to use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() on the field in the dataset with Html text.  Worked great!  Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Great answer... Thanks, Rashid A. Khan